# Is this method of calculating the top-5 accuracy in pytorch correct?

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, imagenet

I am trying to validate the findings of a paper by testing it on the same model architecture as well as the same dataset reported by the paper. I have been using the imagenet script provided in the official pytorch repository's examples section to do the same.

```
class AverageMeter(object):
    """Computes and stores the average and current value
       Imported from https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py#L247-L262
    """
    def init(self):
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.val = 0
        self.avg = 0
        self.sum = 0
        self.count = 0

    def update(self, val, n=1):
        self.val = val
        self.sum += val * n
        self.count += n
        self.avg = self.sum / self.count

def accuracy(output, target, topk=(1,)):
    """Computes the precision@k for the specified values of k"""
    maxk = max(topk)
    batchsize = target.size(0)

    , pred = output.topk(maxk, 1, True, True)
    pred = pred.t()
    correct = pred.eq(target.view(1, -1).expand_as(pred))

    res = []
    for k in topk:
        correct_k = correct[:k].reshape(-1).float().sum(0)
        res.append(correctk.mul(100.0 / batch_size))
    return res
top1 = AverageMeter()
top5 = AverageMeter()

# switch to evaluate mode
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(test_loader):
        # measure data loading time
        print(f"Processing {batch_idx+1}/{len(test_loader)}")
        inputs, targets = inputs.cuda(), targets.cuda()
        inputs, targets = torch.autograd.Variable(inputs, volatile=True), torch.autograd.Variable(targets)

        # compute output
        outputs = model(inputs)

        # measure accuracy and record loss
        prec1, prec5 = accuracy(outputs.data, targets.data, topk=(1, 5))
        print(prec1,prec5)
        top1.update(prec1.item(), inputs.size(0))
        top5.update(prec5.item(), inputs.size(0))

print(top1)
print(top5)
```

However the top 5 error which I am getting by using this script is not matching with the one in the paper. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this particular snippet?

Comment: the top 1 score you get matches?

Comment: @Shai the paper hasn't reported top 1 scores for this particular dataset with which I am trying to validate the resuts.

Comment: what is the dataset and by how much are you "off"?

Comment: @Shai It is off by a large margin the paper reports it to be around 17 I am getting it around as 31. This is the dataset  https://github.com/rgeirhos/texture-vs-shape/tree/master/stimuli/style-transfer-preprocessed-512  I am trying to use.

Comment: @WaveShaper it is there in the code snippet i provided. i just wanted to know whether there is any mistake in this script or not?